# printing os_log from xcode device console

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios10, nslog

As you may know that the ASL was replaced with the unified logging system in iOS 10.

I tried to import

```
import os

if #available(iOS 10.0, *) { print("XXXXXX");  os_log("This is a log message."); }
```

but it's not showing the os_log or the print in device console.

print does output in the xcode console though.

any comments are greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Console` app (Apple added it for macOS Mojave), which is, as Xcode, also in `/Applications` folder.

More about it: https://support.apple.com/guide/console/welcome/mac

Answer (score -1):

[image: Debug enbale screen shot to undertand the viewers about debuging]

Go to **'Edit scheme'** option of your project and then click on **'Run'** menu. Click on **'info'** tab. And then Just Enable **Debug executable** option. then try NSLOG it will work.

Comment: thanks for sharing. i had tried that before posting but it won't show the logs on the Device Console.